# Alternating series: Problems with floating point precision

Tags: precision, cancellation

I have a list of numbers `x` obtained from measurements. I need to calculate the quantity

[image]

where `a` is a positive number. Unfortunately, the individual terms of the sum can be very large and the sign of each term is determined by `k` and the associated value of `x`. This leads to cancellation and loss of precision.

I have found a couple of approaches such as [compensated summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) but wanted to check whether I am on the right path and whether there are better alternatives.

Comment: This may be better suited for the [math section](http://math.stackexchange.com).